# PhpStorm: how can I replace specific word with regex

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I have this script in my php page :

```
<div id="add-new-head"><?php echo __("EDIT_MY_ACCOUNT_DETAILS") ?>
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">     
....    ....    ....
    <div id="add-new-head"><?php echo __("EDIT_MY_ACCOUNT_DETAILS") ?>
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">     

        ....    ....    ....
    <div id="add-new-head">REGEX
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">     

                ....    ....    ....
    <div id="add-new-head"><?php echo __("REGEX") ?>
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">     

                ....    ....    ....
    <div id="add-new-head">REGEX
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">
```

In PhpStorm I <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + R</kbd> to replace all `REGEX` to `<?php echo __("REGEX") ?>`, but not the lines containing the `__` function

I've used the `"(?m)^(?!.*\__\b).*$"` expression to select all lines that don't contain `__` function and I use `.*add-new-head.*` expression to select the attribute to help me change the value.

My question is how I can combine the first and the second expression exactly to replace all `REGEX` with `<?php echo __("REGEX") ?>` ?

Comment: is not about output , i  just wanna replce all REGEX in my project with __("REGEX") , i have 50000 word like this , and i think if i can do a replace that will be cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `(REGEX)$` assuming REGEX is always at the end of line with no characters after it.

Then replace with `<?php echo __("\1") ?>`  where `\1` corresponds to the first capture group.

**UPDATE:**

Since you want to capture everything between `"add-new-head">` and the next tag start `<` you can use the following.

Find : `("add-new-head">)([^<\s]+)`

Replace with: `\1<?php echo __("\2") ?>`

Output:

```
<div id="add-new-head"><?php echo __("EDIT_MY_ACCOUNT_DETAILS") ?>
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">     
....    ....    ....
    <div id="add-new-head"><?php echo __("EDIT_MY_ACCOUNT_DETAILS") ?>
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">     

        ....    ....    ....
    <div id="add-new-head"><?php echo __("REGEX") ?>
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">     

                ....    ....    ....
    <div id="add-new-head"><?php echo __("REGEX") ?>
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">     

                ....    ....    ....
    <div id="add-new-head"><?php echo __("REGEX") ?>
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">
```

you can find the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/KmkCyr/1)

Comment: my idea was not just get "Regex" text , but anything after add-head ...; but it's ok ...

Answer (score 2):

This Should Work.

Tested on Notepad++

Search By:

```
REGEX$
```

Replace with:

__("REGEX")

Output:

```
<div id="add-new-head"><?php echo __("EDIT_MY_ACCOUNT_DETAILS") ?>
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">     
....    ....    ....
    <div id="add-new-head"><?php echo __("EDIT_MY_ACCOUNT_DETAILS") ?>
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">     

        ....    ....    ....
    <div id="add-new-head"> __"REGEX" 
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">     

                ....    ....    ....
    <div id="add-new-head"><?php echo __("REGEX") ?>
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">     

                ....    ....    ....
    <div id="add-new-head"> __"REGEX" 
<a href="javascript:{}" title="Close" id="closeBox" onClick="document.getElementById('add-new').style.display='none';"><div class="close">X</div></a></div>
 <div class="inside">    
    <div id="mess" style="position: relative; top: 0;">
```